# How to disable wireless from command line

Tags: wireless, network-manager

How do you disable the wireless Internet from the command line?

I tried `sudo ifconfig eth1 down` but network-manager seems to ignore this and keeps trying to reactivate it. What's worse is the network-manager widget doesn't let you disable it either once it starting "trying to connect". Whenever I'm near a spotty connection, it just keeps trying and trying to connect, failing each time and showing an annoying error message, "sorry, we couldn't connect".

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The command-line equivalent in ubuntu 16.04

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

To re-enable, use

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

To help

```
nmcli radio help   
nmcli radio wifi help
```

Comment: Object 'radio' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu 18.10.  Not sure if I was too impatient, but looks like I had to throw a "sudo" in there to get it to work:  `sudo nmcli radio wifi off`.

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, on Ubuntu 20.04 this command is silently ignored without `sudo`. It should fail _with_ an error message.

Comment: @Stéphane On Ubuntu 16.04, I had to use `sudo` because I was connected to the machine through a remote connection (the `sudo` was needed maybe to prevent a normal user from stopping the wifi). When I logged in locally, it worked fine without using `sudo`

Comment: This does not disable the wireless.  It turns it off.  Any ideas on how to actually disable it?  Do I have to disable the mod for the wifi? `cfg80211              710770  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm`

Comment: As of Jan 2022 and Ubuntu-MATE 21.04 this works nicely without sudo. (also nicely+immedeatly reflected in the top panel network widget)

Answer (score 44):

Enable/disable networking completely

```
nmcli networking off
```

Just for WiFi

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

On both cases `on` to re-enable.

If you need to **permanently** disable a particular *device*, then you can do that programatically using the `unmanaged-devices` feature in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf or (at a lower level) by blacklisting or removing the corresponding driver.

---

For older versions than [v0.9.10](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/nmcli)

- Use `nm` instead of `networking`. See [`nmcli` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nmcli.1.html).
- Table with [differences between nmcli v0.9.8 vs. v0.9.10](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/nmcli).
- The top-level `nm` object no longer exists, and the equivalent `nm wifi` options are now provided by a `radio` object.
- The `nmcli` interface changed significantly between v0.9.8 and v0.9.10, and the documentation notes that:

> Even if nmcli tries to keep backwards compatibility in general, there
>   were requirements during Networkmanager development that forced some
>   incompatible changes in nmcli. The table bellow list differences
>   between 0.9.8 and 0.9.10.

Comment: I _think_ in 16.06 it would be `nmcli r wifi off`  At least that is what worked for me.

Comment: nmcli nm wifi off/on                 work for me in Ubuntu14.04 LTS

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Right, works well. On the contrast, the `nmcli nm wifi off` command throws: Error: `Object 'nm' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'.` Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

In general, simple

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

...should be enough. Sometimes, wireless card can be shown as

```
ethX
```

instead of

```
wlanY
```

then you need to double check which ethX to disable and you can do it with

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and look for your wireless card entry inside which you will find:

```
logical name: <ethX_or_wlanY_goes_here>
```

I guess you probably know and your problem is bigger then that but at the same time, probably lots fresh of people will find this topic and this should be enough for them.

Comment: nice answer for a new user!

Comment: This method works on Ubuntu 19.04, but the nmcli method does not.

Comment: "down" turns the device off. "up" turns it back on.

Answer (score 10):

A method no one mentioned:

`rfkill list` to view wireless/bluethoot devices

`rfkill block <device number>` to (soft) block it

Answer (score 10):

First, install the following package:

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

Now, turning your WiFi connection on or off will be really simple:

```
wifi on
wifi off
```

Great! Even more, you can also toggle your WiFi connection:

```
wifi toggle
```

**Tip:** You can do the same with your bluetooth device using `bluetooth` command.

**Causion:** Although I know this is an Ubuntu forum, however, a caution for Fedora users: If you install TLP package on Fedora, then you might have issues starting RFKill service during boot process. For more information, see [what's RFKill](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/power_management_guide/rfkill) and [this related problem](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?316531-Fedora-27-Failed-to-listen-on-Load-Save-RF-Kill-Switch-Status).

**Warning**: Not sure about every possible case, but TLP might slow down your system, and could cause you experience lags and/or freezes. The reason is, it's mainly a package for improving battery life and usage, perhaps by making your processor mode to powersave.

Comment: This was what I needed! Thanks! =) Now to find an equivalent for brightnessctl...

Answer (score 4):

For me, on Ubuntu 15.04 `nmcli radio wifi off` worked for turning off wifi. To turn off networking in general (including LAN) I use `nmcli networking off`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to toggle the state of the WiFi connection. It might be useful to know.

```
nmcli radio wifi `nmcli r wifi | grep enabled -c | sed -e "s/1/off/" | sed -e "s/0/on/"`
```

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli networking off` and `nmcli radio wifi off` does not work for me in **ubuntu 12.04**! The following commands works for me:

```
nmcli nm status
nmcli nm wifi off
```

Comment: Wow, This works with 14.04 too. Amazing!! Thank you