# Turn on interface using nmcli

Tags: networking, network-manager, interface, nmcli

I would like to turn my interface on, using nmcli command. 
Command `nmcli device connect wlp2s0` does not work for me, it gives me this error : 
`Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: A 'wireless' setting is required if no AP path was given.`

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: I turned off wifi in GUI. Now I want to turn it on using bash. `nmcli networking on` works only if the interface was previously turned off by `nmcli networking off`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable wireless from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597116/how-to-disable-wireless-from-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to man page

```
   nmcli radio {all | wifi | wwan} [ARGUMENTS...]

   Show radio switches status, or enable and disable the switches.

   wifi [on | off]
       Show or set status of Wi-Fi in NetworkManager. If no arguments are supplied, Wi-Fi
       status is printed; on enables Wi-Fi; off disables Wi-Fi.

   wwan [on | off]
       Show or set status of WWAN (mobile broadband) in NetworkManager. If no arguments are
       supplied, mobile broadband status is printed; on enables mobile broadband, off
       disables it.

   all [on | off]
       Show or set all previously mentioned radio switches at the same time.
```

`nmcli radio wifi on`

Comment: Yep, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: I get the same identical error as op but this doesn't solve it. The radio is already enabled