# How can I prevent Wi-Fi from turning off?

Tags: wireless, system-settings

I was inspecting my power settings and noticed that my [Wi-Fi can be turned off to save power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuRkg.png). And there's no way to change that setting from the GUI. Is it possible to change it from the terminal?

Comment: Your attached picture sh ob / off switch to the right of the text. Try turning that switch off todisable the fuction ....

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the slide on the far right as shown in the picture?

Comment: @SorenA I have tried that, it actually turns off my Wi-Fi.

Comment: @David Yeah, that turns off my Wi-Fi.

Comment: @vanadium No, it doesn't. Did you read my question? I'm trying to *prevent* Wi-Fi from turning off...

Comment: I have retracted the close vote - your question related to the terminal however is a duplicate there. Anyway, you are misunderstanding this option: it is confusing, but it has nothing to do with automatically turning it off. The switch just allows you to manually turn it on or off, no more, no less. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The label on that option, "Wifi can be turned off to save power" is somewhat confusing. It is more simple than it appears: the only thing the option does is allow *you* to turn wifi of. You can turn it off by clicking the switch to the right of the option to save power while you do not need a connection.

To turn on/of using the terminal, see this question: [How to disable wireless from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597116/how-to-disable-wireless-from-command-line)